# Netty echo server can't handle 100+ channels

Tags: java, netty, nio

I want to create chat-server which would handle 100-500 users in different rooms.
I decided to use Netty framework, because of event-based arcitecture (which is very familiar to me). I started with small server which respond "NYA" for everything it recieve.
main:

```
    public class ChatServer{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService bossExec = new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(1, 400000000, 2000000000, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ExecutorService ioExec = new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(4 /* число рабочих потоков */, 400000000, 2000000000, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        ChannelFactory factory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(bossExec,ioExec);
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(factory);

        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory(){
            public ChannelPipeline getPipeline(){
                return Channels.pipeline(new ChatChannelHandler());
            }
        });

        bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
        bootstrap.setOption("reuseAddress", true);

        bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(5555));

        System.out.println("ChatServer started at last...");
    }
}
```

handler:

```
public class ChatChannelHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

    private final ChannelBuffer messageBuffer = ChannelBuffers.dynamicBuffer();
    private boolean processingMessage = false;
    private short messageLength;

    @Override
    public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Connection from: " + e.getChannel().getRemoteAddress().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
        e.getChannel().write(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer("NYA!", "UTF-8");
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getCause());
        Channel ch = e.getChannel();
        ch.close();
    }
}
```

I use simulation program which creates N connections and then randomly write stuff to server with 1-5 second pause. Then i connect with my Flash-based client, to see how it is working. So problem is that under 10-90 connections my flash client immediately get responds from the server, but when number of simulated connections exceed 100 my flash client remain silent. I simply don't understand why.
I figured out, that all messages from my 100+ client gets into buffer, but messageReceive event simply not fired for them. Looks like event queue reachs some limit of registered events, or something like that.
It's really sadden me, because i read about even simpler servers handles 1k+ request per second.
I work under Windows 7, if it is necessary. Also my server never use more then 2-3% of CPU.

My simulation generator:

```
public class ClientLoadEmulation implements Runnable {

    private String host;
    private int port;
    private static final int minStringLength = 5;
    private static final int maxStringLength = 40;
    private static final int minPause = (int) (1 * 1000);
    private static final int maxPause = (int) (5 * 1000);
    Random rand = new Random();

    public ClientLoadEmulation(String host, int port, int numThreads) {
        this.host = "192.168.0.100";
        this.port = 5555;
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
            new Thread(this).start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        byte buffer[] = new byte[255];

        try {
            Socket s = new Socket(host, port);
            InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
            while (true) {
                String govno = "";
                ...STRING GENERATION STUFF CUTTED...
                ByteBuffer LENGTH_BUFFER = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
                LENGTH_BUFFER.putShort((short) govno.length());
                LENGTH_BUFFER.flip();
                out.write(LENGTH_BUFFER.array());
                out.write(govno.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " wrote " + govno);

                int pause = minPause
                        + (int) (rand.nextDouble() * (maxPause - minPause));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(pause);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
                }
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ie.getMessage());
        }
    }

    static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        new ClientLoadEmulation("127.0.0.1", 5555, 100);
    }
}
```

(Sorry for my English skills)

Comment: I have had some test recently and figured out, that with 100+ conections accepted my browser can't load any page. It looks like i simply ran into my network adapter limit for TCP/IP connections. Is it possible?

Comment: But im not sure, because server accept connections without delay. And when i stop simulation application server begin processing queued client, so i can see all staff written over time in one big message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your sample, but when I tried to run ChatServer you provided, it was not waiting for the client conneciton, but rather quit.

Moreover I don't see there port 5555 setup at all (the one expected from the client).

Please post the working sample to check.

Comment: that's interesting as I tried your sources on my winXP with netty 3.5.3 final and I get reply correctly. I just added System out for data recieved by client (including client thread id) as well as System out for length of the client sleep and all works fine, even with 300 clients.

Comment: Thank you for testing! Now i really think that problem is in my adapter or someth.

Comment: if your messages seem to be queued, did you try to use: out.flush(); after out.write(govno.getBytes("UTF-8")); ? I also checked for limits in win 7, there seems to be only half-open connection limit, see: http://superuser.com/questions/4582/is-there-a-half-open-tcp-connection-limit-in-win-7?rq=1 and check if playing around with that helps